# Rails Nested Form and dependent relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, foreign-keys, scaffolding

I currently have a few models, users, clients, addresses and contacts.

I used scaffold to create my client model which only contains name, leadsource and DBA. It is currently working just fine.

My address and contact was created separately as a client can have many addresses and contacts and they require a client_id to set up the relationship.

Assuming I am using your standard crud operations, is there any way to set up a single nested form that will allow me to add all 3 at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, the standard way is `fields_for`.
But normally you also want to dynamically add and remove associated objects (i.e. addresses) and that's a bit more advanced.

There are gems to help you. i.e. [`cocoon`](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) and a great railscast: [episode 403](http://railscasts.com/episodes/403-dynamic-forms).

Unfortunately it's a pro episode, but investing the $9 is well worth it, as the railscasts really are a source of inspiration (at least for me).

I assume, you already have the associations or create them:

```
rails generate migration AddClientReferenceToAddress client:references
rake db:migrate
```

and in models:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
end
```

Comment: Thanks Martin! For removing objects together I would just add dependency into the relationship on the model, correct?

Comment: I've always debated signing up for railcast but I took your word on it and just went with it, Cacoon looks exactly like what I need! I appreciate the help!

Comment: unfortunately Ryan stoppt creating new railscasts more than two years ago. I hope he's fine.

Comment: Cocoon is magic! Took me a bit to figure it out as the documentation for your standard coding isn't very easily obtainable but once I got it running it's really cool. Have you ever tried to display cocoon in tabs? Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: yes, I also use it in tabs, even several cocoons on one tab. Runs like charm. I use fieldsets to wrap the partials of one association and cocoon stay in this fieldset and doesn't disturb others. b.t.w think about accepting my answer.